# CreateFilter() for IDictionary<Key, Val> in HQL

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I'm trying:

```
db.CreateFilter(x.dict, "DictionaryValue = 1 order by CreateDate");
```

but this is not valid HQL.  How do I write this filter in HQL?

Here is the code:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual IDictionary<B, int> dict { get; protected set; } //int is 1 or -1
}

public class B
{
    public virtual DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

Which is mapped as:

```
<map name="dict" table="TABLE">
  <key column="ID_A" />
  <index-many-to-many column="ID_B" class="B" />
  <element column="FACTOR" type="Int32" />
</map>
```